# `gx` on visual selection in keymap in NeoVim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I would like to map `gp` to open the file name inside the current set of parentheses.

I have:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'gp', 'vi(gx', {noremap=true})
```

However, this just selects the text inside parentheses and leaves me in visual model, rather than executing the `gx` keys.

I confirmed that my map is correctly set with `:nmap`:

```
n  gp          * vi(gx
```

Comment: `gx` itself is a mapping, from netrw. So you'll need to set `noremap` to `false`. (Just be careful of possible recursion when doing that; for the current scenario, there should be no problem with `noremap=false`.)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the help. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.